# Scripted expression to make a positive constraint value turn negative as target bone rotates (Empty Head only Art)

Tags: drivers

I've been avoiding using drivers for a while for this exact reason:

No matter how many tutorials I look at, my math-dead head has no idea how use a driver to make one of my action constraint values go from 1.00 to 0.05 when a target bone rotates so I can blend between action constraints.

I'm an art school bachelor burnout! I don't have a single molecule of BEDMAS math in my brain!